# Sublime Text 2 Project file build system for js files prevents JSHint from running on save

Tags: sublimetext2

I have setup Sublime Text 2 to run JSHint when JavaScript files are saved. The easiest way to achieve this seemed to be to use the plugin [SublimeOnSaveBuild](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild) together with the [JSHint](https://github.com/uipoet/sublime-jshint) plugin. And it works great.

The problem is that I now need to run an additional shell command when JavaScript files are saved. This is project specific, so I added a build system to the .sublime-project file (`echo Test` is just a placeholder for the real command).

```
"build_systems": [
   {
     "name": "RunOnJavaScriptSave",
     "selector": "source.js",
     "cmd": ["echo Test"],

     "windows": {
       "shell": true
     }
   }
]
```

This is now triggered when JavaScript files are saved, **but it stops JSHint from running**. It seems the "source.js" selector conflicts with the JSHint plugin.

I located `Packages\JSHint\JSHint.sublime-build` and indeed it also contains a "source.js" selector:

```
{
  "selector": "source.js",

  "cmd": ["jshint", "$file", "--reporter", "$packages/JSHint/reporter.js"],

  ...
}
```

While not very elegant, my "solution" is to run jshint in my build system as well:

```
"build_systems": [
   {
     "name": "RunOnJavaScriptSave",
     "selector": "source.js",
     "cmd": "jshint $file --reporter \"$packages/JSHint/reporter.js\" && echo Test",

     ...
   }
]
```

This works, but surely there must be a more elegant way to have several build systems that use the same selector (source.js in my case) and have them all run on save?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can share your source.js ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. "source.js" is not an actual file?